# How to blur background image on hover but not the text

Tags: javascript, css, image, text, blur

Hello I just started web developing and I am stuck at trying to blur the background image of a div on hover, but without affecting the text.

As you can see I have an id called c1 and I used a javascript function to display text on hover, which is working great.

Now I want to use css/javascript to blur the background image without bluring the text. Is this possible?

My CSS:

```
#c1 {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 15px;
    background-image: url(images/cd.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 150px;
}

#c1:hover {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="productos">
    <a name="jproductos"></a>
    <ul>
        <div id="c1">
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Khalid in order to accept an answer you can click the tick beside the answer until it turns green. 15 points for the answerer and badge for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to structure your html differently. If you make a relative container and place the image as a separate div from the text:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>

.container{
    position: relative;
}

.image, .text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.image{
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

This way the text and image aren't parent/child/same element and you can blur only the image, but still have the text appear as if it is on the image

Answer (score 1):

```
#c1 {
 position:relative;
 float: left;
 width: 300px;
 padding: 30px;
 margin: 15px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 height: 150px;
 overflow:hidden;
}

#c1:after{
 content:'';
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:-1;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 bottom:0;
 right:0;
 background: url(images/cd.png) no-repeat center;
 background-size: cover;
}

#c1:hover:after{
 -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Comment: This works really good! Thanks a lot. Now what is happening is when I hover on the text it (the text) disappears. If this can be fixed I would be ever grateful! :D